# Laravel 5 Custom Validation - Custom MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, validation, laravel

I'm designing an app that involves checking promotional codes. I have researched (Google), but I could not find resource that would explain resolution to similar problem, or problem that can be translated to this one.

> Table : **Users**
>
> *Id, Name, email, etc.*
>
> Table : **Codes** (Winning Codes)
>
> *Id, Code, Value*
>
> Table : **SubmittedCodes** (Codes submitted by users)
>
> *Id, User_id, Code, timestamps*

User would check where code he submits have any value, and submitted codes would be remembered if particular users would want to submit too many codes.
Validation would be thrown back to view. Saved in SubmittedCodes table.

I would like to ask you whether my approach is correct? Should I use Custom Validation? Should I build Custom Helper? Maybe some specific MySQL query?

I don't want anyone to code this for me, just need nudge in the right direction. I think I know how to use a search engine, but I may have missed some.

I have done simple tutorial about custom validation, but this one had other objective and I couldn't adopt it to my requirement.

Currently I have build sign/up user management system with messages and admins, but this part/module is bit difficult.

Links to resources I have mentioned above:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-validation-rules
https://scotch.io/tutorials/laravel-form-validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't make complete sense of your question, but from what I gather (and please correct me if I'm wrong) you want a user to submit a code and if it matches a code in the codes table then store it in the submitted codes table, right?

You could use the [`exists`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-exists) rule in this case, as you are checking ***if*** a code exists in the codes table.

So in your validator for your form submission you would add the rule like this:

```
'user_submitted_code' => 'exists:codes,code'
```

You can also shorthand it if the field name matches the column name in your DB

```
'code' => 'exists:codes'
```

Hope that helps! Please leave a comment if I didn't address your question.

Answer (score 0):

As described by @haakym, you can use the exists rule to validate if that code does exist in the first place.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'user_submitted_code' => 'exists:codes,code'
]);
```

Once that is done, you want to check if that code has been used by a specific user.

```
$check = SubmittedCodes::where(
    ['user_id', $user_id],
    ['code', $user_submitted_code]
)->exists();
```